# Como pegar uma variável javascript de outra pagina?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Por exemplo, em uma pagina tem uma tag script desta maneira:

```
<script>var X = "variável que quero pegar";</script>
```

Como poderia fazer para pegar essa variável "X" em outra pagina apenas com a **url** dela e transportar para pagina atual? Considere que a pagina pode ser de **url externa** do servidor.

Comment: As variáveis ​​não podem ir de uma página para outra. Se forem do mesmo site pode usar localstorage, cookies entre outros recursos.

Comment: E se desse de ler o texto da pagina com Javascript e retornar o texto? por exemplo, ler oque está entre "<script>Conteúdo...</script>" e retornar esse conteúdo?

Comment: Com PHP seria possível

Comment: Quero evitar o uso do servidor, vou tentar com  XMLHttpRequest, caso não dê vou recorrer a ele mesmo, obrigado pela sugestão

Comment: Cara, o que daria para fazer é mandar uma requisição para página em questão, utilizar um regex ou um parser de XML para pegar o valor de dentro da tag script e depois dar um `eval` nesse valor. Mas isso é gambs das braba, só usaria em ultimo do ultimo caso.

Comment: Compreendo kkk, mas vou tentar com PHP ou JavaScript